# Connection not closed when using Tomcat DataSource container

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat

I have a config of my server.xml in Tomcat 7:

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" global="jdbc/MyDB" maxActive="100" maxIdle="8" maxWait="10000" minIdle="0" name="jdbc/MyDB" password="XXXX" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:postgresql://myServer:5432/SomeDBName" username="postgres"
        removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="20" logAbandoned="true" maxAge="600000"/>
```

Upon init of my wepapp, the following code is executed:

```
DataSource dsRand = (DataSource) getContext().lookup("some jndi to the database");
```

Upon login in my webapp, the following code is executed:

```
Connection conRand = null;
Statement stmtRand = null;
ResultSet rsRand = null;

conRand = dsRand.getConnection();
stmtRand = conRand.createStatement();
...
finally {
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(rsRand);
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(stmtRand);
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(conRand);
}
```

Then, before I log in to my webapp, I check the connections table in my Postgres database using:

```
SELECT datname,procpid,current_query,backend_start,client_addr, to_char(now()-backend_start, 'HH24:MI:SS') as age FROM pg_stat_activity ORDER BY backend_start;
```

- I see that no connction to the database is present in the resulting table. This is expected.

Then I log in and a connection is now present. And it just sits there, it doesn't close. Shouldn't it be removed from the table when I call close() on it?

Currently, I have 2 connections to the database both from my browser, and I'm the only one logged in (test environment). The query I mentioned above shows that the age of the connections are 1.5 hours and 0.5 hours, which doesn't correspond at all to the Tomcat DataSource container definition, afaik.

What am I doing wrong here? Do I misunderstand something here?

PostgreSQL 8.4.22, Tomcat 7.0, Java 1.7

Best regards,
Janus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat datasource is using a connection pool.
So

> > DbUtils.closeQueitly(conRand)

in your finally block
is NOT closing the connection to the db,
but is just
returning the connection to the pool.

With your configuration

> maxIdle="8"

causes up to 8 connections to "stay open" for re-use.

Use configuration on the datasource resource (in conf/server.xml) 
for controlling 
whether connections will be kept (and how many)

For details please refer to [Tomcat 7 Datasource HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)
or [Tomcat 7 Pool Attributes](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes)

Comment: Yes, you are right... actually, my question arose from another problem I have (or perhaps had) with my wep app running out of connections. The server.xml conf had a "maxAlive=100" parameter, but the app couldn't get another connection even though only around 10 or 15 connections were present in the PostgreSQL server connections overview.

Comment: What is the value of max_connections in your PG cluster? Usuall the limit is much higher than 10-15, but regularly far below 100. So your maxAlive="100" is at least dangerous.

Comment: sorry for late reply. max_connections = 200 in postgresql.conf.

Comment: But I guess I see now the troublesome waters I'm in: If my connection strings in server.xml allows 100 as max connections for each resource  (and I have 2 of those), I'm really close to the possibility of running out of connections... but 200 !> 200, so I really shouldn't run out of connections, right? Besides, the resource to which no more connections could be established, was at a max of 60, which is far less than the PG defined max of 200, even in combination with worst case scenario of 100 established connections to the other resource.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that after I changed the resource config to this:

   maxActive="50" 
   maxIdle="5" 
   maxWait="10000" 
   initialSize="5" 
   removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
   removeAbandoned="true"

- I have had no problems with a lack of connections ... but *why* does this "do the trick", since the number of concurrent connections in the first scenario was < 200...

Comment: If "removeAbandonded=true" improved the situation, the this indicates your connections are not returned to the pool properly. They are recoginzed as abandoned and reclaimed from this mechanism. You might try getting some log on suspects setting "suspectTimeout". May be this gives hints on why connections are not returned properly.